# Guide on how to setup authentication via Azure ADFS for an application running on Tomcat

Tags: authentication, tomcat, active-directory, saml, adfs

We have an application running on Tomcat currently and using LDAP as the means to authenticate users to our enterprise AD.
It is required to migrate this application to cloud (on AWS EC2) and to integrate with ADFS over SAML for login with MFA enabled.

Wondering if there are any guides on the the steps to be followed to make this happen ? What are the configurations that I need to enable in ADFS for my application and what configuration changes are needed on tomcat server.xml to have the connector integrate with ADFS rather than LDAP. Thanks.

Regards,
Raunak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Tomcat guru but from the point of view of ADFS and SAML:

You need to use a [client-side SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) in your application. This provides the SAML plumbing.

You then need to add a [SAML RP](https://docs.mattermost.com/deployment/sso-saml-adfs.html) to ADFS.

For MFA, typically you use [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa) to provide the MFA.

(There used to be an on-premises ADFS MFA Server - that is now deprecated).

If that is not an option, there are [third-party providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-additional-authentication-methods-for-ad-fs).